# how to get particular div's elements

Tags: jquery, html

```
function getElement(){
    var iBody = $("#frametest").contents().find(".eod-topbox").html();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHtml=iBody;
    alert(iBody);
}
```

I am using this code snippet.I want to access anchor tag of this eod-topbox class and img tag of nested div and content of anchor tag also.

```
<div class="eod-topbox">
    <a href="some link">dfdf</a>
    <div id="something">
        <img src="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what's your problem actually.?

Comment: You are trying to get a reference to 1. the `<a>`, 2. the contents of the `<a>`, and 3. the `<img>`?

Comment: And this is inside an iFrame I assume ?

Comment: i want content of anchor tag and image tag

Comment: And this iFrame is showing a page from your own website.

Comment: no it is other website @adeneo

Comment: please help if anybody know

Comment: It can't be done, and that's the definitive answer. Javascript has a same origin policy, and you can't access any content on other websites, even in iframes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)